# Enforcing a Maven skin dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, skin

I would like to use the [Fluido skin](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/) for my Maven-based project.
If I add it only in `src/site/site.xml` the `mvn site` fails because the artifact is missing. It ask to manually install the artifact, but I would like to avoid that step for my colleagues.

I've added the following dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And it seems to work: the skin is automatically downloaded by maven when I do `mvn site`. However I do not want that my project be marked as a dependency of that artifact ; I don't want that package to be in the classpath during compile, test, etc.

I don't see any [dependency scope](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-dependency-scope) that would restrict the dependency just for `site:site`.

Did I miss something about dependency scope? Is using dependency for that relationship the right thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have time to try this myself, but I think the following should work:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. This feature is documented in [Maven's classloader documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html#Plugin_Classloaders), so I expect this will work. I'll check tomorrow.